# using sp_executesql to run bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, bulk-insert

I am trying to execute bulk insert statement using sp_executesql.
 I received syntax error:

> Msg 102, level 15, state 1
> Incorrect syntax near '\t'.

my code block are based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure)

Please review my code and advise what went wrong and how can I correct it.

```
declare @filepath nvarchar(500);
set @filepath = N'c:\bcp\textfiles\product.txt';


declare @bulkinsert nvarchar(2000);
set @bulkinsert = 
N'bulk insert product from ''' + 
@filepath + 
N''' with (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = "\t", rowterminator = "\n")';

exec sp_executesql @bulkinsert;
```

in product.txt file, the tab key is used as field delimiter 
    below a sample from the text file
    **Note: first row is 6 columns (productname column has no value)**

> PRODUCTID PRODUCTNAME PRODUCTGROUPCODE    PRODUCTGROUPNAME    INSTOCKFLAG FULLPRICE
>   10001     CA  CALENDAR    N   15

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `sp_executesql`. If you replace the `exec` call with `PRINT @bulkinsert;` - an easy way to perform local debugging - you will see this output:

```
bulk insert product from 'c:\bcp\textfiles\product.txt' 
  with (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = "\t", rowterminator = "\n")
```

Put that in its own window, and you will see the exact same issue as the error you received is now highlighted by IntelliSense (note the red squiggly under the `"\t"` and the explanation in the tooltip if you hover over it):

> [image]

The issue is you are using a double-quote (`"`) as a string delimiter - this is not valid in T-SQL. You need to use single-quotes(`''`) to delimit strings, but because the statement itself is embedded in another string, you need to double them up in order to escape them. So:

```
... @filepath + N''' with (FIRSTROW = 2, 
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', rowterminator = ''\n'');';
```

In fact, in [the answer you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051325/61305), those are single quotes, not double quotes - perhaps a transcription error.